# Unable to get Dojo Textbox Value in Handler

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, dojo, dijit.form

In the key up handler when i try to access the value of the textbox i get an empty string back. this is my code.

```
        dojo.connect(dijit.byId("loginpassword"), "onKeyUp", function(evt){
            if(evt.keyCode==13){
                var value = dijit.byId("loginpassword"); //get a empty string here
            }
        });
```

When i try the same statement outside the handler it works properly. Am I doing something wrong, or is it a dojo bug?

Update:
This was wat i  had actually had

> var value =
>   dijit.byId("loginpassword").value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dijit.byId("loginpassword") is going to return a widget Object, not a string (check typeof)  Perhaps you want to do something like dijit.byId("loginpassword").attr("value") ?